# How Terraform incremental changes should be organized?

Tags: terraform

could you help me to understand

For example I have incremental changes to infrastructure, like `[A] -> [B] -> [C]`, where `[A]` separately can be one server named `i`, `[B]` separately can be second server named `j`, and `[C]` separately can be third server named `k`. In total there should be 3 servers. Every state can be described as `[A] = x, x + [B] = y, y + [C] = z` where `x, y, z` are states in the middle.

My question are

- How to organize incremental infrastructure changes for multiple modules in Terraform without affecting previous modules?
- Is it possible to rollback changes in the middle of the chain eg. `[B]` and get `x`-state or we should follow chain from the last module `[C]` to required in the middle `[B]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time Terraform only considers two states<sup>[1]</sup>: the "current state" (the result of the previous Terraform run along with any "drift" in the mean time) and the "desired state" (described in configuration). Terraform's task is to identify the differences between these two states and determine which API actions are needed to move resources from their current state to the desired state.

This means that any multi-step transition cannot be orchestrated within Terraform alone. In your example, to add server `j` you would add it alone to the Terraform configuration, and run Terraform to create that server. You can then add server `k` to the configuration and run Terraform again. To automate this, an external process would need to generate these progressive configuration changes.

An alternative approach -- though not recommended for everyday use, since it can cause confusion in a collaborative environment where others can't easily see how this state was reached -- is to use the `-target` argument to specify one or more specific resources to operate on. In principle this allows adding both servers `j` and `k` to configuration but then using `-target` with only the resource representing `j`.

There is no formal support for rollback in Terraform. Terraform merely sees this as another state transition, "rolling forward". For example, if after creating server `k` you wish to revert to state `[A]`, you would remove the configuration for server `k` (by reverting in version control, perhaps) and apply again. Terraform doesn't have any awareness of the fact that this is a "rollback", but it *can* see that the configuration no longer contains server `k` and thus know that it needs to be destroyed to reach the desired state.

One of your questions is about "affecting previous modules". In general, if no changes are made to a resource in your configuration (either the config changed, or the resource itself changed outside of Terraform's purview) then Terraform should not try to update it. If it did, that would be considered a bug. However, for larger systems it can be useful to split infrastructure across multiple top-level Terraform configurations that are each applied separately. If a remote backend is in use (recommended for collaborative environments) then [the `terraform_remote_state` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) can be used to access the output values of one configuration from within another, thus allowing the creation of a tree or DAG of Terraform configurations. This adds complexity, so should be weighed carefully, but has the advantage of decreasing the "blast radius" of a particular change by taking unrelated resources out of consideration altogether.

---

**[1]** I am using "state" here in the general sense you used it, which is distinct from Terraform's physical idea of "state", a data file that contains a record of which resources existed at the last run.

Comment: can't upvote, but this is good and straightforward explanation for my question, thank you